# How to update array inside Go model for Mongo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have Player  model in Go for Mongo and model Level

```
type LevelModel struct {
    Index           int                 `json: "index" bson: "index"`
    Time            int64               `json: "time" bson: "time"`
}


type PlayerModel struct {
    ID              bson.ObjectId       `json: "_id, omitempty" bson: "_id, omitempty"`
    Score           int64               `json: "score" bson: "score"`
    Level           []LevelModel    `json: "level" bson: "level"`
}
```

How to update Level from PlayerModel if I have instance of PlayerModel ( player pointer ) ?
Player can play new ( not yet played ) level ( then insert ) or already played ( just update if time is lower then already achieved for that level ).

Answer (score 3):

If this is just about updating a data structure in memory (whether it maps a MongoDB document or not), a naive algorithm can be applied, such as:

```
func (p *PlayerModel) updateLevel(idx int, time int64) {
    for i := range p.Level {
        lm := &(p.Level[i])
        if lm.Index == idx {
            if time < lm.Time {
                lm.Time = time
            }
            return
        }
    }
    p.Level = append(p.Level, LevelModel{idx, time})
}
```

See an example at: https://play.golang.org/p/C8SGqkgZ99

Comment: Thanks for answer but I am confused how is this propagated back to Mongo, model does not have any Save method ( like in SQLAlchemy, I worked in Python, in Go I am newbee)

Comment: It is because it is not a "model" in the sense of SQLAlchemy. It is just the representation of the MongoDB document in memory. In order to save the changes, you need to explicitly write the document back to MongoDB, using Collection.Update or Collection.UpdateId. Note that if you read the document, update it in memory, and save it back to MongoDB, the whole operation is not atomic.

Comment: I understand is not atomic but I cannot update with this validation in atomic way if my data are nested in array ( I know for fields which are not arrays, for example Score from Player ) but I am not sure if there is a way to do in atomic way with nested array with validation

Comment: I did not find a way to do it directly without changing the model (and getting rid of the array), But it can still be done in two steps (read+write) and using optimistic concurrency control (i.e. add a version number in your document that is checked at write time).